# How to change query for make it more quick?

Tags: mysql, sql

It is some query to MySQL db. It is works (historically) but are very bottleneck I suppose.

```
SELECT
tb_real.One,
tb_real.Two,
tb_real.TimestampMs,
tb_real.Symbol,
tb_max.MaxTimestapmMs
FROM (SELECT
  Symbol,
  MAX(TimestampMs) AS MaxTimestapmMs
FROM times
WHERE Symbol = inSymbol
AND TimestampMs < inDateTo) AS tb_max
JOIN (SELECT
    TimestampMs,
    One,
    Two,
    Symbol
  FROM Times
  WHERE Symbol = inSymbol
  AND TimestampMs < inDateTo) AS tb_real
  ON tb_max.MaxTimestapmMs = tb_real.TimestampMs
;
```

It's works but slowly enough. Is it possible to make it simple\quicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the first subquery always selects only one row as soon as `Symbol = inSymbol` so you can just rewrite it as follow. And sure you have to index `Symbol` and `TimestapmMs` fields

```
SELECT
    One,
    Two,
    TimestampMs,
    Symbol,
    TimestapmMs
  FROM Times
  WHERE Symbol = inSymbol
  AND TimestampMs  =   (SELECT
                       MAX(TimestampMs)
                       FROM times
                       WHERE Symbol = inSymbol
                       AND TimestampMs < inDateTo)
```

Also if `TimestampMs` field is unique (Only one record has the MAX value) and this query always returns only one record you can use `LIMIT 1` to get this record:

```
    SELECT
        One,
        Two,
        TimestampMs,
        Symbol,
        TimestapmMs
      FROM Times
      WHERE Symbol = inSymbol
      AND TimestampMs < inDateTo
   ORDER BY TimestampMs DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ok, and if:   CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_get_times` (IN inDateTo bigint)
BEGIN
  SET sql_big_selects = 1;

  SELECT
    tb_real.One,
    tb_real.Two,
    tb_real.TimestampMs,
    tb_real.Symbol,
    tb_max.MaxTimestapmMs
  FROM (SELECT
      Symbol,
      MAX(TimestampMs) AS MaxTimestapmMs
    FROM Times
    WHERE TimestampMs < inDateTo
 GROUP BY Times.Symbol) AS tb_max
    JOIN (SELECT
        TimestampMs,
        One,
        Two,
        Symbol
      FROM Times
      WHERE TimestampMs < inDateTo) AS tb_real
      ON tb_max.MaxTimestapmMs = tb_real.TimestampMs
  ;